# Roles may not be assumed by root accounts

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, aws, vps, amazon

How do I use the `thufir` profile I created, and not use the AWS `root` account?

I'm on page 12 of the *AWS Command Line Interface User Guide*:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat .aws/config 
[default]
output = text
region = us-west-2



[profile thufir]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/thufir
source_profile = default

thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ aws iam list-users
USERS   arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/thufir 2017-01-02T10:09:01Z    /   ABCDEFGIJKL thufir
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ aws s3 ls --profile thufir

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=thufir
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ aws s3 ls --profile thufir

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.
thufir@doge:~$
```

[Page 12 of the *AWS Command Line Interface User Guide*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-roles.html#cli-role-prepare) says:

> After creating the role, modify the trust relationship to allow the IAM user to assume it. The following example shows a trust relationship that allows a role to be assumed by an IAM user named `jonsmith` :
>
> ```
> {
>   "Version": "2012-10-17",
>   "Statement": [
>   {
>     "Sid": "",
>     "Effect": "Allow",
>     "Principal": {
>       "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/jonsmith"
>     },
>   "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
> }
> ```

Is that done locally in a config file physically on my machine, or through a website, or...?

*I think this may relate to roles rather than a **profile** as I have configured.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.

This error means exactly what it says.

You cannot assume a role while using a root account, under any circumstances.  You have to use an IAM account.

There is no other workaround for this.  The behavior is by design.

per:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334769/262852